# Prevent numerical precision error when calculating $\frac1{|Y|}\sum_{y\in Y}\left|f(y)-q(y)\right|$ in a clever way

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, machine-precision

Let $Y\subseteq[0,1)$ be a nonempty set and $f,q:[0,1)\to[0,1)$. I want to compute $$A:=\frac1{|Y|}\sum_{y\in Y}\left|f(y)-q(y)\right|$$ in a computer program.

Now, the problem is that $|Y|$ is large and hence the computation of $(1)$ is slow.

However, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a small $Y_\varepsilon\subseteq Y$ such that $$f(y)<\varepsilon\;\;\;\text{for all }y\in Y_\varepsilon^c\tag1.$$ Moreover, you can assume that it is easy to compute $Y_\varepsilon$ and I already know $$I:=\frac1{|Y|}\sum_{y\in Y}q(y)$$ and hence I don't need to compute it.

If $$A_\varepsilon:=\frac1{|Y|}\sum_{y\in Y_\varepsilon}\left(\left|f(y)-q(y)\right|-q(y)\right)+I,$$ we see that $$\left|A_\varepsilon-A\right|<\varepsilon\frac{|Y_\varepsilon^c|}{|Y|}\tag2.$$

> However, if I implement the computation of $A_\varepsilon$ (in C++) literally, then I've observed that I encounter $$\left|A_\varepsilon-A\right|\ge\varepsilon\frac{|Y_\varepsilon^c|}{|Y|}\tag3.$$ This is most probably to a numerical precision error in the summation. Can I do this in a clever way to reduce the error as much as possible?

**EDIT**: I've asked for the implementation part of this question on StackOverflow as well (but it's slightly different; I didn't want to make things too complicated there): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76136651/547231.

Comment: How do you decide $Y_ε$? Is the summation really the most expensive part or is it the evaluation of $f(y)$ and $q(y)$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I can compute $Y_\varepsilon$ easily by looking up a geometric data structure (since I know that the $y$ which I'm interested in are all in a neighborhood of a given point; that point changes every time I need to compute $A$ though). The most expensive part really is the summation. $|Y|$ can be 1.000.000 for example, but the $|Y_\varepsilon|$ is usually only .0001% of $|Y|$.

Comment: I repeat that a quick solution would be Kahan summation or some binning scheme that accumulates terms at (severely) different orders of magnitude separately.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've implemented Kahan summation and the result got even worse (slightly).

Comment: That should normally no happen. If everything is correct, then in the unchanged summation there is a sufficient amount of operations that have the opposite-sign error to the original, and when this is removed you get this strange behavior.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've added the Kahan summation to the toy example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=9d67c4720848d171.